# How to add html code in the session statements

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4

If the user sign in I want to show this, When I try to  codes with echo I failed how can I do this ?

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
echo 'BELOW CODE HERE';

}
?>
```

I try to add code inside the echo ''. But didnt work how can i do this ?

```
 <div class="col">
<div class="card" >
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does ‘failed’ means ? Use an echo in an wake to see if it’s working first

Comment: I would use HEREDOC syntax:  `echo <<<HTML ... HTML;`

Comment: I have this log syntax error, unexpected 's' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/site/public_html/project/index.php on line 40

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because you wrapped your HTML in single quotes, and used a single quote in the HTML (... *bulk of the card **'** s content* ...).

Try the following using [`HEREDOC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
if($_SESSION['userID']){
    echo <<<EOF
 <div class="col">
<div class="card" >
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div> 
EOF;
}
```

It's a better way of storing HTML or any text really that may contain either single or double quotes.

Comment: yes I have this error log : "syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/site/public_html/project/index.php on line 59"

Comment: Make sure that after `EOF;` there is _NOTHING_, not even a line space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
you have to escape the single quotes present in this line Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the **`card\'s`** content.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
echo '<div class="col">
<div class="card" >
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the `card\'s` content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div> ';

}
```